Help fitting doube-exponential curve to raw mass spec data, time
I am writing mass spec data reduction software in Python for a helium measurement system and could use a hand getting a double-exponential function to fit my data. Basically, the gas in the mass spec chamber evolves over time, and we are trying to fit the raw data back to t=0.
In the past, we have traditionally used a linear fit to our data, since it is over a short enough time period that it is usually linear-seque; however, the gas intensity measured by the mass spec over time is a double exponential function: a negative term for consumption by ionization, and a positive term for ingrowth from memory. Whether consumption or ingrowth will be dominant, or whether the data will just be a scattered mess along the baseline, is often difficult to predict.
I am using the following functions:
def double_exp_func(x, a1, b1, a2, b2, c):
    return -a1 * np.exp(-b1 * x) + a2 * np.exp(-b2 * x) + c


def double_exp_fit(x, y, analysis_raw_std):

    # get the slope and intercept from the linear fit
    slope, intercept = np.polyfit(x, y, 1)
    
    # get the R^2 value from the linear fit
    residuals = y - (slope * x + intercept)
    ss_res = np.sum(residuals ** 2)
    ss_tot = np.sum((y - np.mean(y)) ** 2)
    r_squared = 1 - (ss_res / ss_tot)

    # if the data is scattered, use a minimal exponential contribution to the fit
    if r_squared < 0.8: # for highly scattered data
        p0 = [0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, intercept] # minimal exponential contribution to fit
    else:
        if slope > 0: # for positive slopes, memory/ingrowth is the dominant process (second exp is dominant)
            p0 = [1e-10, slope, 1e-12, slope, intercept]
        else: # for negative slopes, consumption is the dominant process (first exp is dominant)
            p0 = [100, 100, 100, 100, intercept]
    
    def cost_function(params):
        a1, b1, a2, b2, c = params
        fitted_y = double_exp_func(x, a1, b1, a2, b2, c)
        residuals = y - fitted_y
        return np.sum(residuals ** 2)
    
    initial_params = p0
    fit = minimize(cost_function, initial_params, method='Nelder-Mead', options={'maxiter': 100000})
    optimized_params = fit.x
    # fit the data
    # fit, covariance = curve_fit(double_exp_func, x, y, p0, maxfev=100000)
    fitted_y = double_exp_func(x, *optimized_params)
    error = np.sum((y - fitted_y) ** 2)
    
    return optimized_params

I have split the data up into three groups:

Scattered data (linear R^2 < 0.8)
Data with positive slopes, memory/ingrowth is the dominant process
Data with negative slopes, consumption is the dominant process

You'll probably note, however, that the values in the p0 terms are... well, I'm flying blind here. Calling them educated guesses would be an exaggeration.
Here are some examples of the fits provided by my program to raw data:



Note that the lower right-hand plot, 5 amu, always shows an average instead of a fit. This is because 5 amu is our baseline (there are no gaseous species at 5 amu) and is more or less measuring nothing, so there's no reason to fit it to anything. The rest of the plots should have a double-exp fit.
You'll note that the "fits" are just drawing flat lines most of the time, however, in the past I've gotten successful fits to some data with different parameters--but it didn't translate to the rest of the data set.
Here's what I know about the processes involved:

The exponential contribution should be gentle -- after all, this data is close to linear
One of the exponential terms should be locked into being negative, and the other locked into being positive, rather than letting the fitting parameters turn the data negative and positive as needed.
Data with positive slopes have ingrowth as the dominant process.
Data with negative slopes have consumption as the dominant process.

I am new to Python and not a mathematician, though, so I could use some advice getting these pesky double-exponential fits to behave.
What am I doing wrong and how can I improve on the chances of finding a fit?
EDIT: For clarity, here is an example of some raw data in a numerical format:
time_sec    2 amu   3amu    4amu    5amu    40amu
5.489   2.636189E-10    1.888721E-11    7.923646E-13    -1.163915E-14   5.097163E-13
11.689  2.636714E-10    1.889091E-11    7.826869E-13    -9.488767E-15   5.394477E-13
17.689  2.633379E-10    1.888715E-11    7.921988E-13    -1.069696E-14   5.504294E-13
23.789  2.635642E-10    1.888458E-11    7.882167E-13    -1.283497E-14   5.594927E-13
29.889  2.635921E-10    1.882436E-11    7.868621E-13    -7.925926E-15   5.680347E-13
35.989  2.640756E-10    1.883204E-11    7.969135E-13    -1.346417E-14   5.944001E-13
42.089  2.639421E-10    1.886484E-11    7.995152E-13    -1.412389E-14   5.909974E-13
48.189  2.641781E-10    1.887195E-11    7.939710E-13    -1.095929E-14   5.876574E-13
54.189  2.643618E-10    1.881963E-11    7.992858E-13    -1.351132E-14   6.136653E-13
60.389  2.639032E-10    1.885101E-11    7.870530E-13    -1.062203E-14   6.139426E-13
66.389  2.641674E-10    1.878075E-11    7.915301E-13    -7.400502E-15   6.203573E-13
72.489  2.637757E-10    1.878533E-11    7.917193E-13    -8.705283E-15   6.315118E-13
He 19334    JN-001-2A 1.1A 5min H12 2022-06-27T19:55:15


It is extremely difficult to fit a mixture of exponentials to data unless you have a huge amount of data--it's next to impossible to distinguish among them.  What is the reason you want to use such a model?  Before coding anything like this it helps to have experience with nonlinear regression and optimization generally, so consider reviewing some of our threads about that technique..  A good search term here, where many examples are given in R, is nlm.

I want to use a double exponential model because, as I mentioned, that is the actual process at work here and would provide a more accurate intensity at t=0 over a linear fit. I've gotten various successfulish fits in the past, which are encouraging (see https://imgur.com/a/7nRDyxb most are garbage but some are good), and make me think that it is possible if the parameters are correctly constrained. I am not a mathematician and so I don't have a lot of background in this stuff, but I'll do some reading at that link, thanks!

The perfectly realistic model is appealing but it doesn't necessarily achieve higher accuracy at time zero.  In particular, it is likely to increase the standard error of the estimate for $t=0$ compared to a simpler model.  It sounds like your question really is something like "how can I model these data to estimate the response at $t=0$ as accurately as possible?"

Yes, that is accurate: my ultimate goal is to measure the intensity at t=0 as accurately as possible.

A difficulty of fitting especially double exponential is to "guess" the initial values of the parameters. The usual method of non-linear regression involves iterative calculus starting from given values of the parameters. If those values are too far from the unknown correct values the process might not converge properly and give bad result.
I propose to try an unusual method which is not iterative and doesn't require guessed initial values :

The general principle is explain in this paper : https://fr.scribd.com/doc/14674814/Regressions-et-equations-integrales
NOTE : The calculus involves numerical integration (for Sk and SSk). If the data is strongly scattered this calculus becomes not accurate enough and the parameters p and q may become complex instead of real. In this case the model equation should be more complicated with damped sinusoidal terms. In this case the above simple method is not recommended.
Without data given on numerical form it is difficult to test the above method. Only a few cases where treated below in scanning the figures joint to the question. Scanning a graph for numerical data is not accurate. Moreover treating all the examples would be a too heavy work.
FIRST EXAMPLE :

For a better fitting one could use those values of the parameters as good initial values for starting a common iterative method of non-linear regression.
SECOND EXAMPLE :

For a better fitting one could use those values of the parameters as good initial values for starting a common iterative method of non-linear regression.
The examples 1 and 2 are easy cases because the scatter isn't too large. The next example is chosen to show what is appening in case of very large scatter.
THIRD EXAMPLE ( typical case of complex parameters) :

I suppose that this isn't the shape of curve expected.
This means that one should choose another equation model (for example simply linear) to have a more realistic result. Of course the above method without iterative process cannot miraculously solve every case. Nevertheless the cases where the model is not well appropriate and/or the cases of excessive scatter are very easily discriminated between the other cases.
FOURTH EXAMPLE :
This example is added in order to answer to some comment about numerical calculus. A screen copy from MathCad shows the data and the details of the calculus. This might be used to compare with your calculus and check.



FURTHER EXAMPLES From the numerical data provided later :



The two next examples also lead to real equations with sinusoidal terms.

I urge you to test this method, because I expect it to be unstable and possibly unreliable when applied to limited datasets like those illustrated in the question.

@whuber. See the examples of tests added  to my answer.

Well done, and thank you +1.

This is beyond excellent, thank you! I'm wondering if you could share the specifics of your implementation? I am trying to implement this in Python and getting a singular matrix error with the final a, b, c matrix. https://pastebin.com/LQSdfEXX

The error is with invalid value encountered in sqrt because A is negative. I'm not sure how to apply the complex sinusoidal solutions here.

I should mention that A is negative even when I filter this solution to only apply to those fits with a greater than 0.9 linear R^2.

When $B^2+4A$ is negative the root is not real. The proposed method is not recommended  as pointed out in my answer. In this case I doubt that the method be useful in practice. Nevertheless if one want to extend the method to the model equation with sinusoidal terms one need a math software able to operate with complex numbers instead of real only. That is what was done for the third example to compute complex $b$ and $c$. Then $r,s,v,w$ are reals.

Sorry I cannot help you for the implementation in Python. My implementation is much more rustic with MathCad. I could joint the screen copy of an example but I doubt this could help you. Again I don't recomment to use this method in case of complex case.

I would still appreciate seeing the implementation of the real cases, as I am still doing something wrong. A is negative even when the R^2 of the linear fit to the data is above 0.9, meaning that the data are highly cohesive and not scattered. Thus the solution should be real as demonstrated by your examples, however, it always turns out complex.

With MathCad the implementation is not on the form of typed code as in most of the usual softwares. The equations are written on clair form appearing directly on the screen (Implicite complilation all along the algorithm is written). The above example shows the display. If you have MathCad you can copy the example and see the result.

Thank you for adding the fourth example with the math, however, because the y-data is scaled to 10^-10 to 10^-14 in my code, the numbers aren't comparable. Can you please either share the source code for your implementation, or use the raw data from my first example here: https://pastebin.com/gvcgep4A ? EDIT: Just saw your comment about MathCAD, understood. EDIT2: When using this raw data, please ignore the first two rows of data, these are pre-analysis baseline measurements and not part of the analysis

I cannot understand what happen. Can you provide a typical data on numerical form (not graphical).

The issue is that I cannot directly compare our numbers, as you suggested in your fourth example, because my y data are scaled to 10^-10 to 10^-14 whereas your y data are not. I suspect this may be why your model succeeds but mine fails. I have added a set of raw data to the original post.

In addition at end of my main answer : Among the five examples given on numerical form only one has a shape without sinusoidal infuence. This make think that the above method cannot discriminate two real exponenentials in the majority of cases. In other words when the too large scatter hides the shape of real exponential curves. In those cases of too large scatter different equation models (such as only one exponential or more likely simply linear) would probably be more significant. Sorry for this disappointing issue.
