Overfitting in a dual natural logarithm model
I have the following function which models the evolution of gas intensity in a mass spectrometer:
$$y = a \ln(p(t + 32)) - b \ln(q(t+30))$$
which, as JJacquelin has pointed out below, simplifies to:
$$y = a \ln(t+32) - b \ln(t+30) + c\quad \text{where}\quad c = \ln p - \ln q$$
in which the first term represents ingrowth from memory and the second term represents consumption by ionization.

$t,y$ are the independent and dependent variables, respectively.
$a$, $b$, and $c$ are fitted parameters
$32$ represents the start of gas ingrowth from memory before $t=0$ in seconds
$30$ represents the start of consumption by ionization before $t=0$ in seconds

The goal is to determine the intercept of $y$ at $t=0$, representing the theoretical equilibrated gas intensity.
While a single natural logarithm captures the trends of many, many analyses, it falls short for others or requires compensation (reducing the 30 second time offset) in order to capture certain consumptive trends, which compromises its capacity to fit other ingrowth trends.
A "dual logarithm" model, however, produces ideal results in the vast majority of cases:

In a select few cases, however, the model produces unrealistic behavior at low-$t$ values:



This 'swooping' behavior suggests strong early gas consumption before ingrowth dominates, which is physically unrealistic. Generally, low-signal analyses are ingrowth-dominant, high-signal analyses are consumption-dominant, and matched analyses produce noisy trends.
The problem is therefore that the intercept depends too heavily on a few not-even-outlier points at low-$t$, skewing the fit and yielding an unreasonably high intercept. The intercept is not informed by the overall trend, but by the trend of a few low-$t$ data.
The goal is to modify the model to eliminate these swoops without introducing arbitrary constraints (e.g., manually limiting $b$ works, but has no physical justification, so the intercept becomes whatever I want in a certain range based on the boundary).
I have been spinning my wheels on this for days now with no solution in sight. Any guidance, pointers, or proposed solutions would be greatly appreciated.

$$y=a\ln(p(t+32))+b\ln(q(t+30))$$
From wellknown property of logarithm :
$$y=a\ln(p)+a\ln(t+32)+b\ln(q)+b\ln(t+30)$$
$$y=a\ln(t+32)+b\ln(t+30)+c$$
$$c=a\ln(p)+b\ln(q)$$
Regression calculus gives $a$ , $b$ and $c$ but cannot discriminate $p$ and $q$ from knowing only $c$. If a software gives some numerical values $a,b,p,q$ this is not a unique solution but an hazardous particular solution.

In your question it is not clear what you find bad in your calculus and where you are stuck. Also it is not clear what you want.

I think it might be helpful to think about the motivation for this model.  In particular, where do the hard-coded offsets of $30$ and $32$ come from and how is it you have started with an overparameterized model?  These considerations might help you make progress, perhaps by throwing light on a possible model-formulation error or perhaps by suggesting a more effective model.

FYI, the equation describes the evolution of gas intensities within a mass spectrometer. The positive term represents ingrowth from memory, beginning 32 seconds before $t=0$ when the mass spec is cut off from its vacuum pump. The negative term represents consumption by ionization, beginning 30 seconds before $t=0$ when the sample gas is introduced to the MS. I managed to start with an over-parameterized model because I forgot the properties of natural logs, of which JJacquelin reminded me.

Okay, that's good to know.  But that leaves me puzzled, since the standard approach in multiple regression is to test a hierarchy of simpler models and here it looks like your full model isn't statistically significant, suggesting a specific simpler model (or small number of possible simpler models).  Why doesn't this routine analysis solve your problem?

@whuber I'm not sure I follow. I am not a statistician or mathematician and am out of my league here so I am not aware of the "standard approach" nor do I follow what you mean by "this routine analysis". My program already contains a number of simpler models like linear, log-linear, and a single natural log; however, all of these fall short in some area compared to a well-behaved (non-swooping) dual logarithm.

I am trying to wrap my head around why fitted curves show reversals when each predictor should imply a monotonic curve. But although this has been re-opened (rather optimistically in my view) we are still missing much key information, including postings of the data, which would allow discussants to try their own models, and listings of parameter estimates (and standard errors, etc.).  It also seems optimistic to expect that effects of events at 30 and 32 s can be separated given what looks like experimental noise too. That is I think a fact not a criticism.

You are a victim of the notation, so let's simplify it.  Let $X=\log(t+32)$ and $Z=-\log(t+30).$ Your model is $Y=aX+bZ+c+\text{error},$ which is plain vanilla multiple regression; and your question amounts to why the two variables $X$ and $Z$ "overfit." The standard approach to MR is to examine the p-values of the estimates $\hat a$ and $\hat b$ as well as examining the degree of collinearity among your observations of $X$ and $Z.$ That is covered thoroughly in any textbook of multiple regression and is discussed in a huge number of threads here on CV.

@Nick A difference of monotonically increasing curves can exhibit such a reversal.

@whuber Thinking about a bit more, monotonic curves can cross and so their difference can then change sign. I am still wondering what parameter values would cause a reversal for the OP's data.

@Nick Choose the turning point, say $t_,$ and set $b/a = (t.+30)/(t.*+32)$ to make the derivative of $a\log(t+30)-b\log(t+32)$ equal to zero there.

Just as a follow-up, I've given up on this project. The entire reason I was chasing it was because it fit certain curves better, however, I realize now that the improvements in fitting certain curves comes at the expense of non-physical behavior and that the two are inseparable. Limiting the behavior to the physical realm using, e.g., Bayesian regression, produces fits that are effectively equivalent to the single log model but with extra steps.

As a last comment, here is an analysis of the problem using Bayesian regression: https://github.com/AllenDowney/ThinkBayes2/blob/master/examples/dual_log.ipynb in which the results are close enough to the single log model that, imo, the extra processing time is not justifiable.

@ohshitgorillas. Can you joint to your question the data (numerical not graphycal) Your new curves are not consistent with your previous data from https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/647906/help-fitting-doube-exponential-curve-to-raw-mass-spec-data-time .

Without data one cannot reproduce your calculus and see where it's going wrong.

As I mentioned in the above comments, the question is no longer relevant to me. However, for the sake of completeness, I've added some data

Actually, I'm no longer able to identify which analyses yielded which fits. It would take me significant time to go back through and match these plots to their analyses just by comparing the intensities visually. I don't think this is a good use of my time. I can delete the question if that would be better.
